# Let S be the set of all infinitely differentiable functions...

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let S be the set of all infinitely differentiable functions whose domain and range are the real number. Let $S_1, S_2, S_3, $ and $S_4$ be the fours subsets of the S defined below:

$S_1$ = The set of infinity differentiable functions $f(x)$ such that $ \int_{0}^{3} f(x) dx = 0 $

$S_2$ = The set of infinity differentiable functions $f(x)$ such that  $ f''(x) + 2\ln(x)f'(x) = \sin(x)f(x) $

$S_3$ = The set of infinity differentiable functions $f(x)$ such that  $f(x)$ is either always increasing, always decreasing, or $f(x) = 0 $

$S_4$ = The set of infinity differentiable functions $f(x)$ such that  $ (f''(x))^2 = 2f(x)$

How many of the above subsets satisfy both of the following conditions?

1. Given any two functions $f_1(x) $ and $f_2(x)$ in the subset, the function $f_1(x)+ f_2(x)$ is also in the subset.
2. Given any function $f(x)$ in the subset and any real number $c$, the function $cf(x)$ is also in the subset.

You can either guide me to the answer or provide the answer. Whichever would provide the most intuitive solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I do not know how to start with the other sets; however, I have gotten that the monotonic functions satisfy the conditions.

Comment: So, show your efforts.  (Otherwise the question may be closed.)  For example: if $f_1$ and $f_2$ belong to $S_1$, does it follow that $f_1+f_2$ also belongs to $S_1$?  Tell us why or why not.

Comment: I do not know how to explicitly prove it, so I need someone to guide me. But Considering functions such as $x^3$,$e^{(-x)}$, all polynomials with degree 1, log functions, trigonometric functions, functions with discontinuities, absolute value functions, and a few other minorities, we see that these functions satisfy the conditions. If I add two linear functions, the result is still linear and monotonic.

Comment: @KevinPerez, consider $f_1(x)=x,$ and $f_2(x)=1-x.$ Both are infinitely differentiable. Also, $f_1(x)$ is always increasing, while $f_2(x)$ is always decreasing. Hence, $f_1,f_2\in S_3.$ However, $f_1(x)+f_2(x)=1.$ Hence, $f_1+f_2\notin S_3.$

Comment: @aqualubix, you gave me an insightful idea, the fastest way I could get this answer would be just to find a counterargument for the statements. And my mistake, I was still right about the monotonicity I just did not consider constants when checking.

Comment: @KevinPerez, yes, now you may remove $S_3$ from your considerations.

Comment: @KevinPerez, set $S_1$ satisfies both properties. If $\int_0^3f(x)dx=0,$ we can get that $\int_0^3cf(x)dx=0$ by multiplying by $c$ on both sides. As for the additive property, since the limits are the same, we can just add the definite integrals.

Comment: That is, if $\int_0^3f_1(x)dx=0,$ and $\int_0^3f_2(x)dx=0,$ then $\int_0^3(f_1(x)+f_2(x))dx=0.$

Comment: @aqualubix I was working on the same one. $S_1$ may satisfy the first condition, If I have an integral with two areas between 0 and 3 that sum to 0 then could I find any other pair that may cancel terms between them? maybe if get a function of the form X + C and  X, yet when I was checking desmos no other functions of the form X^d would have a drop below y = 0 innately.

Comment: @aqualubix I understand why you said adding the limits on the integrals; however, since we sum the terms inside the functions, what allows you to claim that they will still equal zero when summed? Also, can $S_4$ be manipulated to satisfy the conditions just as you did for $S_1$?

Comment: $S_4 $ works for the first condition. if $ (f''(x))^2 = 2f(x)$ then $ \frac{ (f''(x))^2\{}{2} = f(x)$ which means when we sum them we will get two equivalent functions that cancel out 2 and leave $(f''(x))^2$   which on the right side would equal $f_1(x) + f_2(x)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143076/discussion-between-kevin-perez-and-aqualubix).

Comment: @KevinPerez, check the chat room for my answer to the question you asked me.

Comment: @aqualubix, hey are you good at statistics as well? I have a question that I need some assistance on.

Comment: @KevinPerez, well, statistics ain't my thing, but I'll try it out.

Comment: Are you familiar with the incomplete gamma function?

Comment: Can you explain why in test 3 of this [suite of tests](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf) we are using the incomplete gamma function which the chi-squared distribution.

Comment: @KevinPerez, sorry man, I don't know any of that stuff.

Comment: @aqualubix how about this one, if f'(x) +f(x)  = 1 and f(0) = 2, find f(ln(2))

Comment: @KevinPerez, that is a seperable DE. Letting $y=f(x),$ we get $\frac{dy}{1-y}=dx.$ Integrating both sides, we get that $y=Ce^{-x}+1,$ where $C$ is a constant. But, $y(0)=2.$ This implies that $C=1.$ So, $f(x)=e^{-x}+1.$ This means that $f(\ln(2))=\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: That is a good solution, but does that mean the function is a non-autonomous differentiable equation?

Comment: And I have another question, I thought differentiable equations have to be in the form g(y)*f(x), so does this mean that g(y)*f(x) forms a sum when adding like terms that equals to f'(x) + f(x)? Also, your answer is correct.

Comment: @KevinPerez, I do not understand what you mean by "differentiable equations have to be of the form $g(y)f(x)"$. Please elaborate.

Comment: @aqualubix, sorry I meant separable DE.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate a floor function and a fraction function in the same equation? If you did not know, the integral of the floor function is defined as the sum of integers up to n.

Comment: @KevinPerez, yes I've come across integrals like that before, but whether or not I can solve them depends on the question itself. I can try if you send it to me.

Comment: find the value of $\int_{0}^{100}\frac{\{x\}}{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}$ whereby {x} is the fractional part function.

Comment: @KevinPerez, I know the answer to that question, but it's too lengthy to type out in the comments. I suggest asking that as a question itself so that you may get insight from others too. The basic idea is to consider what happens to the function in the interval $[n,n+1),$ where $n$ is some whole number.

Comment: does it follow something like [this](https://youtu.be/clguMZ44m38)?

Comment: I have the solution [here](https://ibb.co/6JHBkks), all that is needed at the end is to take the geometric sum formula.

Comment: @KevinPerez, yes, your method is identical to mine.

Comment: Ok, well if you are willing. I will give you a free-form set of questions from the same project. If you are doing them you are not allowed to use Taylor series polynomials for the questions and they need to be solved using methods found in calculus 2. This project can be found [here](https://ibb.co/xhTTVVY). I personally need a little bit of help so it would be good if whenever you had spare time and you wanted to do it, you could.

Comment: Also, you might have to use induction for some of them, but it is not meant to be solved in that way.

Comment: @KevinPerez, thanks for the problems. I'll try them out.

Comment: @aqualubix, If you have the chance, could you look at this solution and explain to me how y was removed from the integral? [here](https://ibb.co/cvKDSS3)

Comment: @KevinPerez, the integrand is not a function of $y.$ Hence, when we evaluate the definite integral, we treat $\frac{e^x}{x}$ as a constant.

Comment: Wow, this was a trivial result. Yet I did not know about this, I believed the dy could have been changed by changing the limits on the integral. For example, if you look at the gaussian distribution, you can change the variables in equation to match other distributions.

Comment: @aqualubix A particle is initially at the point(2,0). at t = 0, t starts moving uniformly counterclockwise in a circle of radius 2 such that the particle makes sone complete rotation in 4 seconds. what is the rate of change of the distance between the particle and its initial starting position at t = 2/3?

Comment: @aqualubix, also Areeq moves only available to an elliptical island on a lake described by the equation 9x^2 + 25y^2 = 225. Areeq's new home is located at (4,0) and he placed his chicken nugget far, at (-4,0). The water on the island is along the edge of the island. What is the minimum distance Areeq has tot travel each day?